# vis timeline group Label background colour depending on className

Tags: css, vis.js

I am trying to find the right css class to assign a new background colour to the group label of vis timeline. Here is my jsfiddle example.
[I want to give the Label in front of the coloured area a background colour](https://jsfiddle.net/Kaliph/pLj1n07w/)

```
var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
```

`var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container);`

```
var options = {
    editable: true
```

`};`

```
var groups = new vis.DataSet([
{id: 0, content: 'First', value: 1, className: "default"},
{id: 1, content: 'Third', value: 3, className: "red"},
{id: 2, content: 'Second', value: 2, className: "blue"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the red item ("Third"), then you can set the group label colour with something like:

```
.vis-labelset .vis-label.red {
   background-color: red;
}
```

There are probably better ways to do this depending on the rest of your CSS structure - this is just consistent with the way you did your jsfiddle.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. Yes that makes it going.

Comment: if this answers the question, can you mark it as "ticked"?

Comment: Where can I set "ticked"? I can flag it as should be closed.. Is this what u mean?

Comment: As the asker, you should see a tick (check mark in US English) under the voting buttons on the left side of the answer.